# Record mp3 frames to a file

Tags: c, file, mp3

This is really an intellectual exercise, since C is my favourite language, and I need more experience hacking things.
I have a program that gets MP3 files as frames. I want to write a single C file with a header file that has functions that I can simply "plug in" at various points in the overall program. A single function call, because the program itself tends to be updated, and I want to be able to take my program from one version of the code to the next, with the minimal amount of hacking time each time.

So, how do I turn MP3 frames into an MP3 file? I am a complete newbie at this.

Comment: Just write the frames to a file, or am I missing something?

Comment: Probably not missing anything... but I can't find any documentation to help me do it.

Comment: An mp3 file is just a sequence of frames, so just write the frames to a file and you're done.

Comment: What about writing the metadata, ID3 tags, etc? Start and end of file, anything special?

Comment: id3v1 goes at the end of the file id3v2 goes at the beginning of the file see http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/